# validar si hay coincidencias en arreglos

Tags: php, array

tengo un arreglo que se llama $perfil

```
    array(25) { ["idVacante"]=> string(1) "1" ["fechaRegistro"]=> string(19) "2018-03-06 13:09:48" ["estado"]=> string(9) "Búsqueda" ["idPerfil"]=> string(1) "3" ["idPresupuesto"]=> string(1) "1" ["folio"]=> string(1) "1" ["mes"]=> string(1) "3" ["anio"]=> string(2) "18" ["presupuesto"]=> string(13) "DEMOSTRADORAS" ["nombrePerfil"]=> string(16) "DEMOSTRADORA FDS" ["nombreComercial"]=> string(10) "GAMEXPRESS" ["puesto"]=> string(14) "DEMOSTRADORA A" ["solicitante"]=> string(27) "JORGE CARLOS MEDINA STAINES" ["costoUnitario"]=> string(6) "487.90" ["edad"]=> string(2) "20" ["edadMaxima"]=> string(2) "30" ["idPuesto"]=> string(3) "181" ["salario"]=> string(6) "285.00" ["sexo"]=> string(5) "Mujer" ["escolaridad"]=> string(1) "4" ["diasTrabajados"]=> string(37) "Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes" ["experiencia"]=> string(1) "2" ["conocimientosEspecificos"]=> string(1) "1" ["habilidades"]=> string(3) "3,2" ["paquetes"]=> string(4) "Word" } }

y tengo este arreglo que trae una lista se llama solicitudEmpleo

    array(2) {
 [0]=> array(17) { ["idSolicitudEmpleo"]=> string(1) "1" ["nombresDatosPersonales"]=> string(14) "carlos enrique" ["apellidoPaternoDatosPersonales"]=> string(3) "gil" ["apellidoMaternoDatosPersonales"]=> string(8) "morrison" ["puesto"]=> string(3) "181" ["sueldo"]=> string(6) "400.00" ["diasTrabajados"]=> string(22) "Viernes,Sabado,Domingo" ["idPromocion"]=> string(10) "61,64,69,4" ["edad"]=> string(2) "35" ["sexo"]=> string(5) "Mujer" ["ultimoGradoEstudios"]=> string(1) "5" ["experienciaPuesto"]=> string(7) "ninguna" ["habilidades"]=> string(1) "1" ["paquetesLenguajes"]=> string(24) "Excel,Power point,Access" ["conocimientosEspecificos"]=> string(3) "1,2" ["escolaridad"]=> string(10) "Secundaria" 

 ["puntaje"]=> array(10) { ["conocimientos"]=> int(10) ["paquetes"]=> int(0) ["habilidades"]=> int(0) ["dias"]=> int(0) ["promocion"]=> string(9) "reingreso" ["edad"]=> int(0) ["sueldo"]=> int(0) ["sexo"]=> int(10) ["escolaridad"]=> int(0) ["experiencia"]=> int(10) } } 

 [1]=> array(17)  { ["idSolicitudEmpleo"]=> string(1) "2" ["nombresDatosPersonales"]=> string(15) "victor salvador" ["apellidoPaternoDatosPersonales"]=> string(4) "luna" ["apellidoMaternoDatosPersonales"]=> string(4) "nava" ["puesto"]=> string(3) "181" ["sueldo"]=> string(6) "100.50" ["diasTrabajados"]=> string(44) "Lunes,Martes,Miercoles,Jueves,Viernes,Sabado" ["idPromocion"]=> string(10) "61,64,69,4" ["edad"]=> string(2) "28" ["sexo"]=> string(5) "Mujer" ["ultimoGradoEstudios"]=> string(1) "2" ["experienciaPuesto"]=> string(1) "3" ["habilidades"]=> string(5) "1,2,3" ["paquetesLenguajes"]=> string(22) "Excel,Power point,Word" ["conocimientosEspecificos"]=> string(3) "1,2" ["escolaridad"]=> string(8) "Maestria"

 ["puntaje"]=> array(10) { ["conocimientos"]=> int(10) ["paquetes"]=> int(10) ["habilidades"]=> int(10) ["dias"]=> int(10) ["promocion"]=> string(9) "reingreso" ["edad"]=> int(10) ["sueldo"]=> int(10) ["sexo"]=> int(10) ["escolaridad"]=> int(10) ["experiencia"]=> int(10) }

 }

 }
```

quiero ver si hay coincidencias entre el arreglo perfil y solicitudempleo

estaba haciendolo haci pero me di cuenta que solicitud empleo trae varias filas y perfil solo es una fila

```
public function validarPerfilSolicitud($solicitudEmpleo,$perfil){
        $solicitudesEmpleoValidas= 0;
        if($solicitudEmpleo['sexo'] == $perfil['sexo']){
            $solicitudesEmpleoValidas++;
        }
        foreach ($solicitudEmpleo["sexo"] as $sexo) {

        }

    }
```

**nota: por si no explique bien**

```
$solicitudempleo
array(1){["sexo"]=> string(5) ["salario"]=> string(6) "285.00"}

$solicitudempleo
array(2){["sexo"]=> string(5) ["salario"]=> string(6) "300.00"}

$perfil
array(1){["sexo"]=> string(5) ["salario"]=> string(6) "400.00"}
```

validar si las solciitudes tiene coincidencias con el perfil

Comment: ¿Qué coincidencias exactamente deben ser evaluadas? El array tiene varios datos... creo que le falta claridad a tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias por responder sexo, edad, dias y experiencia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seria algo asi:

```
public function validarPerfilSolicitud($solicitudEmpleo,$perfil){
    $solicitudesEmpleoValidas= array();

    foreach ($solicitudEmpleo as $i => $solicitud) {
        if($solicitud['sexo']==$perfil['sexo'] && $solicitud['edad']==$perfil['edad'] &&
             $solicitud['dias']==$perfil['dias'] && $solicitud['experiencia']==$perfil['experiencia']) {
                $solicitudesEmpleoValidas[] = $i;
        }

    }

    return $solicitudesEmpleoValidas;

}
```

Comment: dejame revisarlo

Comment: gracias pero como sabria que solicitud si cumple ?

Comment: Cuando llames la funcion, tienes que chequear que el array que retorna no este vacio.  Si no esta vacio, el array te devuelve los indices de las solicitudes que coinciden en el arreglo solicitudEmpleo